# MySQL Will not start

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi with MySql installed which has been working fine for 4 months.

I played with 3 settings on MySql and now it will not start.

I changed innodb_log_file_size to 100MB, innodb_buffer_pool_size to 300MB and innodb_write_io_threads to 8.

Then on a reboot mysql did not restart. If I run /etc/init.d/mysql restart I get the error "the partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full"

The SD card has 19GB of space free.

So I modified the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to set the settings back then rebooted but still no luck.

What on earth has happened?

Edit----

I am using Raspbian OS

Ok so I think my partitions are as follows

```
Filesystem       Size      Avail

rootfs           30G       19G
/dev/root        30G       19G
devtmpfs         235M      235M
tmpfs            49M       49M
tmpfs            5M        5M
tmpfs            98M       98M
/dev/mcblk0p1    56M       38M
```

---

I have now tried a new SD Card with a fresh install of raspbian and MySql. I am for some reason getting the same error despite the card only being 29% full. This is on a brand new install trying to start MySql for the first time! What on earth is going on?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of some files.  I assume there are multiple partitions, what is the usage, on the partition?

Comment: I have no idea if there are multiple partitions. How do I tell?

Comment: Research what command would list the number of volumes you have on the operating system your using.  You don't indicate what your using.

Comment: Ok I have edited my post

Comment: None of my partitions have 100% usage the most is 35% and they still have 19G free

Comment: Your unformatted information couldn't be read that problem has been resolved. Which volume contains the `var` directory?  Might also help if you post the contents of `my.cnf` for us

Answer (score 1):

> Then on a reboot mysql did not restart. If I run /etc/init.d/mysql
>   restart I get the error "the partition with /var/lib/mysql is too
>   full"

Free up some space on `/var` or break open your `my.cnf` (if that's the name of the configuration file) and put your database on a partition with more room.

> The SD card has 19GB of space free.

This doesn't mean the partition `/var` lives on has 19GB free.  Your distro, when you installed it, may have only given this partition 1 or 2GB of space.  You may need to move the database elsewhere in your filesystem.

Use a `mount` command to find out what partitions you have, and `df -h` to check the free space on them.

Comment: I have edited my post to list the partition sizes. How do I know what partition MySql is installed on?

Comment: Hmm ... can't tell from that, sorry.  Do a `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: This tells me "proc /proc proc defaults 0 0,/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot vfat defaults 0 2,/dev/mmmcblk0p2 / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1"

Comment: I have discovered that if I delete one of the large dbs then the rootfs and /dev/root partitions both get more available space which suggests these are the install partitions (I assume both are the same thing) Which means there is a load of space available on them.